# A alternative geometric (visual) solution to the derivative of square-root

Tags: calculus, geometry, derivatives, differential-geometry

In [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S0_qX4VJhMQ)  video, 3Blue1Brown shows how one can derive the derivative geometrically. Around 2 min 30 sec, he shows how the derivative of $f(x)=x^2$ is $f´(x)=2x$ by starting with a square.

The key idea is that the change in $f(x)$, denoted $df=dx^2$, captures the change in area. This change has three components: the two rectangles and the tiny rectangle. One obtains the area of one rectangle by multiplying the two sides, that is  $xdx$. The area of the tiny area is $dxdx$. Thus, the change is area is then $dx^2=2xdx+dxdx$. As the derivative is defined as the ratio between change in the input (i.e., $x$) and the output (i.e., $f(x)$), we solve for $dx^2/dx$. By algebraic manipulation, that quantity is $dx^2/dx=2x+dx$. When we let $dx$ approach zero (i.e., taking the limit) in this equation we are left with $dx^2/dx=2x$. Thus, we derived $f´(x)=2x$.

In a similar way, we may derive $f(x)=x^{1/2}$. 3Blue1Brown leaves this as a challenge, and the most common way is to now set the area to $x$ and the sides to $x^{1/2}$. So the area changed is now defined as $dx$, and to obtain the geometric pieces we follow the exact same geometric logic: $dx=2x^{1/2}dx^{1/2}+dx^{1/2}dx^{1/2}$. By algebraic manipulation, we obtain $dx^{1/2}/dx=1/2x^{-1/2}$.
See the following [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/164709/derivative-of-square-root?rq=1) for a complete solution (see particularly Armin Meisterhirn's solution for geometric version).

Now to my question. While I understand that by re-writing the problem of finding $f(x)=x^{1/2}$ by setting $x$ to represent the outcome (the total area), if feel unintuitive to stating the problem like this. It forces us to start the problem by seeking to find the area changes via $dx=...$, which we usually define as the input -- now it is defined as the output. It feels more intuitive to starting with the actual output, and defining the total area in terms of $x^{1/2}$ and not $x$. And then focus on  $dx^{1/2}=...$, but what would such an area be? Inspired by the fact that $f(x)=x^2=xx$ that lends itself to the two sides of a square, why not write $f(x)=x^{1/2}=x^{1/4+1/4}=x^{1/4}x^{1/4}$. And so we set the sides of the square to $x^{1/4}$. That would enable us to write down the more intuitive expression $dx^{1/2}=2x^{1/4}dx^{1/4}+dx^{1/4}dx^{1/4}$. However, I was unable to manipulate this expression algebraically, to make it equal to $dx^{1/2}/dx=1/2x^{-1/2}$.

The key problem is that I could not obtain $dx$ from $dx^{1/2}=2x^{1/4}dx^{1/4}+dx^{1/4}dx^{1/4}$. I can factor out one, $dx^{1/2}=((2x^{1/4}dx^{1/4})/ dx +(dx^{1/4}dx^{1/4}/dx))dx$, and then $dx^{1/2}/dx=((2x^{1/4}dx^{1/4})/ dx +(dx^{1/4}dx^{1/4}/dx))$
but such a move creates an ugly and complicated expresion for I am not sure what the limit is.

My question is two-folded: (1) do you see a way to continue along my more intuitive path algebraic, and (2) if not, why does my intuitive method not work?

<s>Might it be that exponential does not lend themselves to a generalized geometric solution? 3Blue1Brown hints that this is the case in the follow up [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m2MIpDrF7Es&list=PLZHQObOWTQDMsr9K-rj53DwVRMYO3t5Yr&index=5). But then what is the limitation of this approach to the derivative (it can be used for sin, cos, and other complicated functions).</s>

My problem is related to [Derivative of Square Root Visual](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2824922/derivative-of-square-root-visual)

and
[Derivative of square root](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/164709/derivative-of-square-root?rq=1)

Comment: A point of vocabulary: $f(x)=x^n$ (either for $n=2$ or $n=1/2$ or any other **fixed** exponent) is not an exponential function ; an exponential function has a **variable** exponent :$f(x)=a^x$.

Comment: see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2577136).

Comment: @JeanMarie, you are absolutely right. I edited that part of my questions by adding a strikethrough.